# How to populate "multiselect" with data coming from json object?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I cant seem to populate the multiselect field with the data coming from json object. Its not helping no matter which multiselect I use. Data is showing in inspect mode but not showing in fontend.
It was supposed to look like this.

[image]

but it comes as this. No options are coming.

[image]
My html code:

```
<div>
   <span>Tags</span>
   <select id="choices-multiple-remove-button" placeholder="Select upto 5 tags"   name="tags" multiple></select>
</div>
```

My js code:

```
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        var tagOption = ('<option value=' + value.Id + '>' + value.Name + '</option>');
        console.log(value.Name);
        $('#choices-multiple-remove-button').append(tagOption);

    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        var multipleCancelButton = new Choices('#choices', {
            removeItemButton: true,
            maxItemCount: 5,
            searchResultLimit: 1,
            renderChoiceLimit: 2
        });
    });
```

My json data:

```
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Tasty",
    "TimeStamp": null,
    "FOodOrTravel": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Smells Bad",
    "TimeStamp": null,
    "FOodOrTravel": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Spicy",
    "TimeStamp": null,
    "FOodOrTravel": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "Name": "Expensive",
    "TimeStamp": null,
    "FOodOrTravel": 1
  }
```

console.log(data)
[image]

Comment: Try changing name to `name="tags[]"`

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: Please dump `data`.

Comment: can you explain it a bit please. I'm new to these terms.

Comment: Try: var tagOption = "<option value='" + value.Id + "'>" + value.Name + "</option>";

Comment: I have already tried that. But its not working either. Upon inspecting the html form created perfectly with those option. But they aren't showing on the selectbox.

Comment: try to execute the code inside a document ready event.

Comment: Dumping means to display the raw data of a variable. In this case the result of `console.log(data)`.

Comment: Move the code into the document.ready function or wrap it in a function and call that from the document.ready function.  Until the page has been loaded, the select list won't be available, so the code has nothing to append to.

Comment: This is actually inside a document ready function. In fact data is coming from web api.Heres the full script. https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/TcZWVHZVFv/

Comment: @Ahmed - the code in this question is different from the linked code as only the var multipleCancelButton... function is within a document.ready block.  This means that the code will function differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                
                url: 'https://codeforces.com/api/user.blogEntries?handle=Fefer_Ivan',
                method: 'GET',

                success: function (data) {
                    

                    $.each(data.result, function (index, value) {
                        var tagOption = ('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.title + '</option>');
                        
                        $('#choices-multiple-remove-button').append(tagOption);

                    });
                    var multipleCancelButton = new Choices('#choices-multiple-remove-button', {
                removeItemButton: true,
                maxItemCount: 5,
                searchResultLimit: 5,
                renderChoiceLimit: 5
            });

                },
                error: function (jQXHR) {
                    if (jQXHR.status == "401") {
                        $('#errorModal').modal('show');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                        $('#divError').show('fade');
                    }
                }
            });
            
        });
```

```css
.mt-100 {
    margin-top: 100px
}

body {
    background: #00B4DB;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0083B0, #00B4DB);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0083B0, #00B4DB);
    color: #514B64;
    min-height: 100vh
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/raw/upload/v1569006288/BBBootstrap/choices.min.css?version=7.0.0">
<script src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/raw/upload/v1569006273/BBBootstrap/choices.min.js?version=7.0.0"></script>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100">
    <div class="col-md-6"> <select id="choices-multiple-remove-button" placeholder="Select upto 5 tags" multiple>
    
        </select> </div>
</div>
```

Here is the working example of your code. Try this one. This is what you want> Finally :)

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/mjg7r1q0/49/]
```

And you used

```
var multipleCancelButton = new Choices('#choices', {
```

You must use

```
var multipleCancelButton = new Choices('#choices-multiple-remove-button', {
```

ANd here is sync method. because script runs before aync methods result

```
https://jsfiddle.net/2bqp8zxo/2/
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                
                url: 'https://codeforces.com/api/user.blogEntries?handle=Fefer_Ivan',
                method: 'GET',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    

                    $.each(data.result, function (index, value) {
                      
                        var tagOption = ('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.title + '</option>');
                        
                        $('#choices-multiple-remove-button').append(tagOption);

                    });
                    

                },
                error: function (jQXHR) {
                    if (jQXHR.status == "401") {
                        $('#errorModal').modal('show');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                        $('#divError').show('fade');
                    }
                }
            });
            var multipleCancelButton = new Choices('#choices-multiple-remove-button', {
                removeItemButton: true,
                maxItemCount: 5,
                searchResultLimit: 5,
                renderChoiceLimit: 5
            });
        });
```

```css
.mt-100 {
    margin-top: 100px
}

body {
    background: #00B4DB;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0083B0, #00B4DB);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0083B0, #00B4DB);
    color: #514B64;
    min-height: 100vh
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/raw/upload/v1569006288/BBBootstrap/choices.min.css?version=7.0.0">
<script src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/raw/upload/v1569006273/BBBootstrap/choices.min.js?version=7.0.0"></script>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100">
    <div class="col-md-6"> <select id="choices-multiple-remove-button" placeholder="Select upto 5 tags" multiple>
    
        </select> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't actually what I'm expecting.The listbox im expecting is to show the items and I would be able to searh them and select multiple items without using "ctrl" key. Similer to this one. https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/multiselect-dropdown-list-83601849

Comment: @Ahmed is that ok?

Comment: Yes this is what I want. In your case its working like charms. But My code is same is yours one but data isn't coming. could it because I'm fetching the data through api inside .ajax block ?

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WYCvq7Jd2c/ here it is. inside a js script.

Comment: @Ahmed could you show me your result? And you used `console.log(value.Name);` this. what is the output of this line?

Comment: It shows the tag names. https://imgur.com/a/NRC1h4H

Comment: Yes it works finally. Thank you so much for saving my day .